# How to have multiple text widgets with scrollbars in a frame on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want my text widgets to have `scrollbar` capability within each text widget. I have created a `canvas` and within it have embedded a `frame` using `create_window`. I then put 2 Text widgets into this frame. I want each of the text widgets to have a scrollbar, however when I add the scrollbars one of them fits the entire frame whilst the second one fits half of the frame. How would I solve this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox

class Main(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    '''This initialisation runs the whole program'''
    #textBoxList = []

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.title('Untitled')
    self.geometry('500x500')
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
    self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas) # frame does not get pack() as it needs to be embedded into canvas throught canvas.
    self.scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
    self.frame.bind('<Configure>', self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))

    # 1st Text Widget
    self.journal = tk.Text(self.frame)
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.vsb.config(command=self.journal.yview)
    self.journal.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    self.vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.journal.pack()

    #2nd Text Widget
    self.good = tk.Text(self.frame)
    self.vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.vsb2.config(command=self.good.yview)
    self.good.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb2.set)
    self.vsb2.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.good.pack()

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry abour that, I edited the code so that it is MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues (apart from the messed-up indentation which probably just happened when pasting your code):

1. The `frame` was bound to the returned value of a function rather than to a function itself. You can fix this with a `lambda` function.
2. You're trying to create a complex layout with `pack()`. Try `grid()` instead.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''This initialisation runs the whole program'''
        #textBoxList = []

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Untitled')
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas) # frame does not get pack() as it needs to be embedded into canvas throught canvas.
        self.scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda x: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))) # lambda function

        # 1st Text Widget
        self.journal = tk.Text(self.frame)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame)
        self.vsb.config(command=self.journal.yview)
        self.journal.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.journal.grid(row=0, column=0) # grid instead
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns') # grid instead

        #2nd Text Widget
        self.good = tk.Text(self.frame)
        self.vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame)
        self.vsb2.config(command=self.good.yview)
        self.good.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb2.set)
        self.good.grid(row=1, column=0) # grid instead
        self.vsb2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns') # grid instead

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, could you possibly expand on issue 1 as I don't really understand: a) how frame is bound to a returned value                                                      b) How providing lambda makes it bind to a function instead

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769851/commands-in-tkinter-when-to-use-lambda-and-callbacks) for more info on that. Basically, something like `multiply(2,3)` isn't a function, it's just the number `6`. The `lambda` keyword defines a function and basically serves as a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but you can work around it by creating a frame for each text/scrollbar pair.

```
    first_text_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
    first_text_frame.pack()
    # 1st Text Widget
    self.journal = tk.Text(first_text_frame)
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(first_text_frame)
    self.vsb.config(command=self.journal.yview)
    self.journal.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    self.vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.journal.pack()

    second_text_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
    second_text_frame.pack()
    #2nd Text Widget
    self.good = tk.Text(second_text_frame)
    self.vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(second_text_frame)
    self.vsb2.config(command=self.good.yview)
    self.good.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb2.set)
    self.vsb2.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.good.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have two text widgets, one on top of the other, each with a scrollbar on the right, `pack` is the wrong choice of geometry managers. You should either switch to `grid`, or use some internal frames to make things fit.

Your other choice would be to create a custom class that is a frame which contains one text widget and one scrollbar. Then, create two instances of this class and pack one on top of the other.